# slideshow working in firefox but not internet explorer

Tags: javascript

Any one help please the page is:

http://weblink.computersforpeople.info/users/1/properties/518/images/2869

why it doesn't work in Internet Explorer, but ok for other browser.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE cannot read your `imagearray`.

Your last image in the array has a comma after it, followed by a comment stating to not include a comma after the last element. The IE error indicates your `imagearray` is empty, I suspect this is the problem.